# How to display tiles based on an array

Tags: arrays, numpy, mapping, 2d, noise

I've created some very basic perlin noise and simplified it like so.

```
from PIL import Image
col = Image.open("noise3.png")
grey = col.convert("L")
bw = grey.point(lambda x : 0 if x<128 else 255, "1")
bw.save("converted.png")
```

so the output image is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C1W9.jpg

From this image I have then converted into an array like so:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("converted.png","r")
pix_val = list(im.getdata())

Map_Array = np.reshape(pix_val, (-1, 128))
```

which outputs a 2D array based on every pixel in the image.

```
[255 255 255 ...,   0   0   0]
[  0   0 255 ...,   0   0   0]
[  0   0 255 ...,   0   0   0]
..., 
[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 ...,   0 255 255]
```

From this 2d array how can I plot these to the screen for example where it says 255 a blue rectangle can be displayed and if it says 0 then display a red one? Obviously later I would hope to assign textures rather than colours but that's currently not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PIL Image to Numpy Array

First of all, don't convert a PIL Image to Numpy Array in such way. It will ruin the pixel order. Instead, use

```
Map_Array = np.array(im)
```

Since there're only two values in `im`, `Map_Array` will be a bunch of `True` and `False`. If you really want it to be `0` and `255`. Do so

```
Map_Array = np.array(im, dtype=np.uint8)    # Contains 0 and 1.
Map_Array[Map_Array==1] = 255
```

### Plot

Simply plot with `pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(Map_Array)
plt.show()
```

The two colors might not be blue and red due to the default colormap. Create a custom colormap of blue and red to plot the image in your colors.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('CustomMap', [(1, 0, 0),  (0, 0, 1)])    # Red and blue.
plt.imshow(Map_Array, cmap=cm)
plt.show()
```

Refer to [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) for more information about custom colormap.

Comment: Thanks just what I needed to display the image. However using the method of conversion to a numpy array that you have stated results in a scaled down image that appears to be tessellated. http://imgur.com/a/KY8sn

Comment: Scaled down? I've got the perfect output image. http://imgur.com/r7yak3D. What is the shape of your Map_Array?

Comment: Map_Array = np.array(im)
Map_Array[Map_Array==1] = 255                                                            Using this i get the scaled down version show in the first picture from the link above. From the original code i get the same output as you. Map_Array = np.reshape(pix_val, (-1, 128))